# Rate limit increase for API token?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I've seen lots of mention here and on the web of the rate limit of 600 requests in 600 seconds, though it doesn't seem to be specified on Facebook's Developer site itself. Is there a way to request a higher limit? If not (and assuming we can't reduce the number of requests) what's the recommended way around the limit? Alternating between multiple tokens?

Comment: There is no 600 requests in 600 seconds limit.

Make sure to always use user access token when possible.

What does your app do?

Comment: We analyze posts from fan pages, so requesting posts and comments from specific pages. So we're currently using one token but are hitting limits and are wondering if we can get an increase in the limit. But I can't find any way to contact FB about this.